# Efficient way to call a method of class stored in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, class, pandas, numpy

assuming a simple class like :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def add2(self):
        return self.level + 2
```

what would be the most efficient way to create and store this class in a DataFrame passing parameter values from the DataFrame it self. Then I would like to efficiently call the `add2` method for that new columns

I have a working approach but I am wondering if I can be more efficient:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 10), columns=['ex'])
class_creator = np.vectorize(MyClass)
df['class'] = class_creator(df['ex'])
df['add2'] = df['class'].apply(lambda x: x.add2())

df
Out[14]: 
   ex                                            class  add2
0   1  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9A58>     3
1   2  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C92E8>     4
2   3  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9A90>     5
3   4  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9AC8>     6
4   5  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9B00>     7
5   6  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9B38>     8
6   7  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9B70>     9
7   8  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9BA8>    10
8   9  <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000000000E1C9BE0>    11
```

I am not sure if np.vectorize is the most efficient way to create all my classes. I am also wondering if there's a better way than using apply to pass the add2 method to the class object on each row.

thanks for help

Comment: You've killed any hope of efficiency using `object` dtype anyway... `apply` is just a vanilla python for-loop under the hood, and so is `np.vectorize`. And you aren't storing *the class* in the `DataFrame`, you are storing *instances of the class*

Comment: that's my point.. looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Don't use a user-defined object, and make your DataFrames use built-in dtypes, preferably numerical. Without knowing what you are trying to do, you can't say much else. There is no more efficient way of working with `object` dtype. Under the hood, there are now `object` dtype numpy arrays, which are essentially bad python `list`s.

Comment: Presumably you have a motivation for trying to do this with a user-defined type... if you add into your question what you're _actually_ trying to do someone may be able to give you a much better answer :)

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for clarification. the class is obviously more complex. the class represent the blackscholes approach to price options (calls and puts) and the method of that class represent all the greeks calculation ( delta, gamma, theta, vega) of the options. I was looking for a way to pass all inputs of a dataframe to that blackschole class to extract all greeks efficiently (if that makes any sense)

Comment: @StevenG i don't see the motivation for placing that in a DataFrame necessarily..

Comment: @Mitch, the DataFrame is helping me not getting lost too much, I have about 100 options per day for 7000 days. keeping that in a timeseries is just easier to acces imo.

Comment: @StevenG Perhaps store a key for a mapping to your objects in a df then? I don't know, tough to say without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: i`ll look it up, but overall I think the comments answer the main question: for classes into  a DataFrame approach, efficiency is not really achievable using that framework.

Comment: It would be just as efficient to use 2 list comprehensions, one to make the objects, and one to run `add2`.

Comment: @hpaulj oh good idea, testing for speed.

Comment: Yeah, this will almost certainly be faster using vanilla python rather than `numpy`/`pandas`, which isn't designed to deal with this sort of thing. You *can*, which is a testament to `pandas`, but it won't take advantage of any of the efficiency benefits of the `pandas`/`numpy` stack